# How to move a Picture with JQuery keyDown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I am a beginner in web programming. I am learning at "CodeAcademy.com". I was making a small page to practice what I already learned, but something is wrong with my code.
[Here is the Page](http://www.codecademy.com/users/51c6f009631fe9fe4f01b2d7/projects/500c7558d143430002002551)

I wanted to make the logo move on pressing W A S D and wrote the code, but something is wrong.

My HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src='script.js'></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js">     </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='menu'>
        <h3>Header 1</h3>
        <div><p>The jQuery UI library bestows on us a lot of magic, including the datepicker widget. We saw how to use that in the date picker project, but with our knowledge of JavaScript, we can add all kinds of bells and whistles.</p></div>
        <h3 id='h3'>Header 2</h3>
        <div id="move"><img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/9aba2f4a04dbccedb70a93033b55b166?d=retro&s=140"/></div>
        <h3>Header 3</h3>
        <div><img id='2' src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/9aba2f4a04dbccedb70a93033b55b166?d=retro&s=140"/></div>
    </div>   
</body>
```

And My JS.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('#menu').accordion();
    $('#2').draggable();
    $('#move').keydown(function(key)
    { 
    switch(parseInt(key.which,10)) 
       {
            case 65:
        $('#move').animate({left: "-=10px"}, 'fast');
        break;
    case 83:
        $('#move').animate({top: "+=10px"}, 'fast');
        break;
    case 87:
        $('#move').animate({top: "-=10px"}, 'fast');
        break;
    case 68:
        $('#move').animate({left: "+=10px"}, 'fast');
        break;
    default:
        break;      
       }
   });
```

});

what's wrong with it?

Comment: CodeAdademy has their own forums for question about their tutorials. You can go [here](http://www.codecademy.com/forums/web-beginner-en-jtFIC) to ask your jQuery related CodeAcademy questions

Comment: @Zeaklous Who said this is from a tutorial? The OP says `I was making a small page to practice what I already learned`

Comment: @Ian The forums there are also for that. I'm not saying he shouldn't have posted there, just letting him know that they have their own (I myself look over them often)

Comment: @Zeaklous Ahh okay, it just sounded like you were saying they shouldn't post this here. Good suggestion then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OH finally found the answer, I had a problem in CSS code, I should have made some of the objects position:relative.

```
h3{
border:2px solid black;
border-radius:5px;
background-color: #8C001A;
margin-bottom:0;
}
body{
background-color:#800517;   
}
#menu div{
border-radius:5px;
background-color: #C11B17;
position:relative;
}

#profile{
background-color: #7D0552;
height: 200px;
}
#move{
position:relative;
}
```

thanks everybody for help :)

Comment: Yes, you must set a `position` property on the `element` if you want to change the `top`, `right`, `bottom` or `left` value.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if its your problem, but this isn't a proper selector:

`$('move')`

It should be .move, or #move.

Comment: changed that but it still doesn't work :( maybe it's not working because the picture is in one of the menu tabs... I don't know. I don't have that much knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8BaP5/)

You need to bind the `keydown` function to the document `body` tag.

So you need to replace the current code with

```
$('body').keydown(function(key){
```

And change your `case` statement to:

```
switch(parseInt(key.which)) {
```

So your full code should be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   $('body').keydown(function (key) {

       switch (parseInt(key.which)) {
           case 65:
               $('#move').animate({
                   left: "-=10px"
               }, 'fast');
               break;
           case 83:
               $('#move').animate({
                   top: "+=10px"
               }, 'fast');
               break;
           case 87:
               $('#move').animate({
                   top: "-=10px"
               }, 'fast');
               break;
           case 68:
               $('#move').animate({
                   left: "+=10px"
               }, 'fast');
               break;
           default:
               break;
       }
   });
```

});

Comment: You can start IDs and classes with numbers, I don't know where you're getting that from

Comment: @Ian Well OK, technically valid in HTML5, but not in CSS if you actually want to style it using `#2 {}` etc.

Comment: I assumed you meant it's valid in every way, when you didn't specify that. But that's interesting, I'm not sure I knew that. Then again, I've never been in that situation because I don't start my `id`s/`class`s with a number. I think that's weird that they don't match up - you can do it in HTML5, but not CSS

Comment: And it is possible to use in CSS: `#\32 { }` is the equivalent of what you expect `#2 {}` to do